# Plugin update not reflected in Wordpress plugin page

Tags: plugin-development, svn

I've created a plugin and added it to WP plugins repository.

Later, I've seen few mistakes on `readme.txt` file. So I've fixed it and commited the changes:

```
svn add --force trunk/readme.txt
svn ci -m 'Fix readme.txt'
```

Then, the changes have been reflected on [WP plugin page](http://wordpress.org/plugins/need-to-share/).

I've done a few more changes on the same file and commited them again, but the last change is not updated on the WP plugin page.

As you can see [here](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/need-to-share/trunk/readme.txt), the SVN repository has the last update, but it is not reflected on [WP plugin page](http://wordpress.org/plugins/need-to-share/) (look at "Description").

[Here](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/log/need-to-share/) is shown the last update ("Fix 4 readme.txt").

As it is my first WP plugin, I'm not sure if I just have to wait some more, or there is something wrong on my last update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The marked answer is wrong. Changing the version doesn't cause this to happen.

The directory updates quickly, but not instantly. There is a delay and you need to account for that or just be patient. There is more than one server and not all of them update at the same time.

Regarding your plugin, you have a couple of problems with it now:

1. Your readme.txt is now incorrect, stating the plugin is version 1.0.1 while the plugin itself states that it is version 1.0. The wrong plugin version is here: http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/need-to-share/trunk/index.php
2. Your Stable Tag in the readme.txt is incorrect, because you do not have any tagged versions. The Stable Tag should either be set to "trunk" or the line should not exist at all, unless you're using tagged builds. No tagged versions here: http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/need-to-share/tags/